# Delete row if value in column matches a fixed cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a fairly simple book in/out system

We track the item from delivery confirmation --> arrival on site --> dispatch from site with a register at each point

I've got all the coding sorted except deleting the record once the item is copied to the next stage

IE:
ITEM 1 is in the 'awaiting delivery' sheet with all its relevant info, it's details get pulled across onto the 'entry to site' form where more info is added then when an input button is pressed, this data is copied to the 'on site' register and I need the code to then delete the old record

In my head it would be a code to use one cell (B1, sheet 2) to find the matching record in the previous sheet (searching in row A:A of sheet 1) and then deleting the row with that record

Thank you! (I'm very much a VBA newbie that's been thrown in the deepend so will try help as much as I can!)

Comment: `Rows(zz).EntireRow.Delete` where `zz`would be the row number you want to delete.

Comment: Downvotes are likely coming from not posting what you have so far: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ideally its just a new bit of code that doesn't interact with the rest as its pretty much 50% VBA 50% excel formulas so wouldnt be of much use posting my code

Comment: Also can't really post the spreadsheet as its a protect proprietary document

Comment: There are numerous items you could look into on SO that deal with this kind of stuff. Look into `.Find` or `.Match` to get a row and apply to @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns his line for starter.

Comment: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [MCVE] , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Comment: @imnotcharlotte: Please show us [what you have tried](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete sheet1 rows that = sheet2 range("B1")

```
Sub Delete_B1()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, FrNg As Range, x


    Set Sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set FrNg = ws.Range("B1")

    With Sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For x = LstRw To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(x, 1) = FrNg Then .Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Next x

    End With

End Sub
```

If you want to delete the A:N cells, then shift cells up.

```
Sub Delete_B1()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, FrNg As Range, x


    Set Sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set FrNg = ws.Range("B1")

    With Sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For x = LstRw To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(x, 1) = FrNg Then
                .Range("A" & x & ":N" & x).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next x

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Brill thank you!! What part of the With Sh would I change to make it delete cells A-N on that row it finds

Comment: @DavesExcel, if you are going to answer this, then could I suggest making use of `.Find` instead of looping through all rows unneccesarily?

Comment: @JvdV- What do you mean by " if you are going to answer this"? I did answer it.